# The process was killed by the system. Why?

Tags: command-line, pdf, imagemagick

I was trying to convert large pdf file to jpg images by command line, using ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 tool (Ubuntu 18.04).

```
convert -density 300 file.pdf page_%.jpg
```

It gave no output, just message that the process was killed after 10 minutes of processing and 3 minutes of freezing (%CPU - 99.0). Why it happened?
Other pdfs were converted perfectly. This pdf file has 222 pages and 89M.

Comment: Take a look at your kernel's log with the command `dmesg`.... it looks like kernel's OOM-killer killed your process.

Comment: You could cut it first with ghostscript, e.g.: `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=40 -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf`

Comment: Thanks a lot. dmesg said, it was not enough memory. I killed a few processes and it works!